# CAPTCHA prompts me to copy a string of code into a box. Then what?

Tags: support

I was trying to post a question, but I had to do a CAPTCHA before I could submit. I did the the 'click all the oranges' test then it prompted me to copy a string of text into a box. I did this, but there isn't any way to proceed from there. No submit or next button.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind. It seems it’s a problem with the *Disconnect* Chrome extension. I disabled that and was successful.